# What version of jdk does Play 1.2.2 need anyway?

Tags: java, playframework

I can't run Play:

```
C:\Dev\play-1.2.2>play run \dev\myFirstApp
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.2, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~
Could not execute the java executable, please make sure the JAVA_HOME environmen
t variable is set properly (the java executable should reside at JAVA_HOME/bin/j
ava).

C:\Dev\play-1.2.2>
```

But I set my environment variables as follows:

```
C:\Dev\play-1.2.2>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming
asl.log=Destination=file
...
\JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local
...
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME should be set to:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17
```

Not its bin subdirectory.

Comment: That fixed it.  I'm surprised I'm able to get all my Java Apps to work.